# External symbol link error when "compile as" set to 'default'

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I have a global variable declared in a C source file (`file1.c`) and used in a method defined in a C++ source file (`file2.cpp`). A header included from both files declares the variable as `extern`. The project property `C\C++ -> Advanced -> compile as` is set to `defualt`, which according to the documentation means the compiler uses the file extension to infer file type. This setup results in an `unresolved external symbol` linking error. If I set this option to either `Compile as C code` or `Compile as C++ code`, the project compiles and link without an error. I fail to understand this behavior. (Btw, under linux/GCC the code compiles OK).

Here's a minimal example reproducing the problem:

```
// file1.h
extern int g_i;

// file1.c
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

int g_i;
int main() {
    g_i = 1;
    foo();
    return 0;
}

// file2.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void foo();

// file2.cpp
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

void foo() {
    int i = g_i;
}
```

Comment: What symbol is it complaining about?

Comment: Do you need an `extern "C"`on the declaration of `g_i`?  (Pedantic note:  file.c doesn't *declare* the variable - it *defines* it.  The header file declares it.)

Comment: @MartinBonner: It complains about `int g_i`. I thought it was clear, as it is the only global variable.

Comment: It might have been complaining about `foo`.

Comment: @MartinBonner: To be pedantic: both are actually declarations. The one in the implementation file is also a _tentative definition_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Language linkage applies to variables as well as functions.  In the C file you define a variable `g_i` which obviously will have C language linkage (from the point of view of a C++ compiler).  In the CPP file (or at least the header file) you need to declare the variable as having C language linkage.  So what you need is:

```
// file1.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
extern int g_i;
```

Alternatively, assuming that the real code has more than one variable in the header file, you may prefer:

```
// file1.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern int g_i;
... // More declarations to taste

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

GCC obviously doesn't distinguish between C and C++ linkage for variables (which is perfectly allowable).

If you force everything to be compiled as C or if you force everything to be compiled as C++, then of course the definition of the variable and the usage of the variable are defaulting to the same language linkage - so it just works.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage for details.  In particular

> ... every variable name with external linkage, has a property called
>   *language linkage*.